# Error while using windows for application and linux for database

Tags: php, mysql

I have my files in Windows OS and Database in Linux Os. When I hit the url in browser, I got following error,

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://192.168.1.211:3306) in D:\Xampp installed files\xampp\htdocs\mobilewebservice\DBconnect.php on line 3

Please help me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: `The target machine actively refused the connection` tells you pretty much exactly what is going on here. Generally speaking, _active refusal_ of a connection indicates a firewall.

Comment: did you even READ the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your mysqld on? Is it really on that IP? Is `networking` turned on in my.cnf (by default it should be.) The firewall possibility was already mentioned by Colin.